# How to add UITabbar, to SingleViewApplication in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I need to implement this functionality help me, Is it possible in SingleViewBased application. Add the buttons to `UITabBar`, `UIButton`, `UIImage` and under `UIButton`, `UIImage`, add the `UILabel`.

Comment: What have you tried? Best to be more detailed about your attempts on StackOverflow.

Comment: Can you please be clear with your requirements. Because your question is not clear enough. DO you want to add TabBar or adding components over TabBar to customise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just drag out a `UITabBarController` in storyboard, and connect drag from the `UITabBarController` to your `mainViewController` and select the relationship segue.

You can set the `tabBarItem` in storyboard to either your custom `image`/`label`, or a system default image and title of your choosing all in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible with the drag and drop directly using storyboard. you can use storyboard and avoid bunch of the code.

Comment: Now I took the uitabbased application but not adding extra items to uitabbar

Comment: now you have to add customally all the images,button and everything into tabbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `UITabBar` by code only. Add it to to singleton instance of `UIWindow`, it will look uniform in the app.

```
self.tabbar = [[UITabBar alloc]initwithFrame:......];
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[self.tabbar setAutoresizingMask:(
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth       |
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin  |
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin   |
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin
                                  )
 ];
if (!window)
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
[[[window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:self.tabbar];
```

You can add this tabbar directly to window also `[self.window addSubview:self.tabbar];` but above code will help rotating it when you rotate your device.